# Does Cauchy imply boundedness?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\{X\}_i~i = 1,2,\cdots$ be bounded and independent random variables. Form the sum $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Let $S = S_{\infty} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ i.e,  $S_n$ converges to $S$ a.s  [Ian's comment]

Suppose $S_n$ is Cauchy (in prob.).

Can we conclude that $S$ is bounded a.s?

Comment: 1 is true by definition inasmuch as $S$ even makes sense in the first place. Anyway, what do you think about this question?

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. I was thinking that if $S_n$ is Cauchy and we know $S_n$ converges. So $S$ must be finite. 

Argument: Say $S$ is not finite. As we know that the series converges, it must be Cauchy. But to establish Cauchy we need finiteness. 

There is some circular argument that I am not sure about.

Comment: Except $S_n$ is a sequence of random variables, not a sequence of numbers. So defining the infinite sum in the way you've described it automatically implies that the sum converges, at least a.s. A better way to frame it would be "does $S_n$ converge to something a.s."?

Comment: @Ian There is a theorem which says that a series of independent random variables converges in distribution iff it  converges in  probability iff it converges a.s., so existence of $S$ is automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. Let $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 2}$ be independent random variables such that $P\{X_n=1\}=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and $P\{X_n=0\}=1-\frac 1 {n^{2}}$. Then $P\{X_n \neq 0\}=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ so $\sum _n P\{X_n \neq 0\}< \infty$. By Borel Cantelli Lemma $P\{\lim \sup \{X_n \neq 0\}\}=0$ so the series  $\sum X_n$ converges almost surely. This implies $S_n$ converges almost surely, hence in probability so $\{S_n\}$ is Cauchy in probability. However, $S=\sum_n X_n \geq k$ if $X_1=X_2=...=X_k=1$ and this event has positive probability [$(1-\frac 1 {2^{2}})(1-\frac 1 {3^{2}})\cdots (1-\frac 1 {k^{2}})$ to be precise]. It follows that $S$ is not a bounded random variable even though $|X_n|\leq 1$ for all $n$.